# Comparing Polygons for Similarity

Tags: geometry, polygon

What are the usual methods to compare two polygons for similarity? Vertices are in 2D.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will find [some methods exposed here](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr00/cs598b/lectures/polygonsimilarity/polygonsimilarity.pdf).

- Turning function
- Graph matching
- Shape signature by deformation

It is used in domains such as [image retrieval](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/e6c8/1b6b0c05aabb062c9f92cd9fd772955e5cdf.pdf) (p. 52), where turning function is illustrated.

Comment: Second link is 404.

Comment: @Townsheriff Thank you. I don't seem to find (eleven years later) a new source for that document.

Answer (score 1):

Something similar: [Shape Similarity](http://www.cs.umu.se/kurser/TDBAfl/VT06/algorithms/BOOK/BOOK5/NODE196.HTM)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't read about the turning function discussed by @VonC, but I suspect a correlation of the vector(s) containing the difference in slopes between the segments would work well.